# CSS issue - aligning a span to another

Tags: css, alignment, html

I'm making an error message, using a pointer image that should give the left side a border. You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dshFk/2/).

My current css is:

```
span.arrow {
    background-color:white;
    background: url('http://i45.tinypic.com/201d0n.png') no-repeat left center;
    height:17px;
    display:inline-block;
}
span.error {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:2px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:10px;
    height:15px;
    font-size:small;
    border-top:1px solid #99182c;
    border-right:1px solid #99182c;
    border-bottom:1px solid #99182c;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #888888;
    position:relative;
    top:-2px;
}
```

And html to display the error:

```
<span class='arrow'>
    <span class='error'>
        Errormessage.
    </span>
</span>
```

Now first of all, the code seems a bit messy. Like having to position the span up two pixels is a bit strange. Nevertheless it seems to work in Chrome, FF & Opera, but not in IE9.

If it isn't clear: the box should perfectly aline with the triangle-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
span.arrow {
    background: url('http://i45.tinypic.com/201d0n.png') no-repeat left center transparent;
    line-height:17px;
    padding-left:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
span.error {
    padding-right:2px;
    background-color:white;
    line-height:15px;
    font-size:small;
    border-top:1px solid #99182c;
    border-right:1px solid #99182c;
    border-bottom:1px solid #99182c;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry did not update the fiddle. It is http://jsfiddle.net/dshFk/6/ I checked it in IE9

Comment: Oh right, I was a little puzzled that it was the 'old' fiddle. The updated one seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
span.error {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:2px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:10px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-size:small;
    border-top:1px solid #99182c;
    border-right:1px solid #99182c;
    border-bottom:1px solid #99182c;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 10px #888888;
    position:relative;
    top:-2px;
}
```

Generally if you make your line-height match your content area height, the text will be vertically aligned.

http://jsfiddle.net/dshFk/3/

I looked in IE and it looked fine.

Comment: May I ask why you are doing it this way? Is it so you can have a single image and editable text? You are not going to have good results doing it in this method.

Comment: Does it look like that in Fiddle. Looks fine in my Fiddle.

Comment: Yes, straight from the fiddle.
And I'm doing it like this so I can have dozens of errormessages. It's for a form validator so there's a lot of different errors. Didn't think it would be so much of a hassle

Comment: Well, you are relying on all browsers to display the font the exact same way.

Comment: If you are not worried about older browsers just use `border-image` and just use a plain box or javascript fall back for ones that don't support it.

Comment: Can't really figure out how to do it with `border-image`. I don't really want to use another image either, since the image I'm using now is already being utilized somewhere else on the site where it'll be implemented.

Comment: You can make a single image and with border-image that image can scale in size to your needs. Why not use another. I am telling you, trying to get fonts,borders,and images to all align perfectly is tough. Hence the reason border-image was created.